# Not able to place a lien on a project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to set the VPC sharing for my organization. To start with I am trying to create a lien on central project. Even though I am the oranizational admin, I am not able to set restrict lein project removal on my organizational policy. Here is my command and error that is thrown

```
gcloud alpha resource-manager org-policies enable-enforce     --organization ORGID  compute.restrictXpnProjectLienRemoval
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.resource-manager.org-policies.enable-enforce) User [MyID] does not have permission to access organizations instance [ORGID:setOrgPolicy] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission
```

I did a gcloud init and also reauthorized myself. No luck. I also tried the beta command for the same. What should I do ? Please help.

Comment: Try adding the `Compute Shared VPC Admin` role to your identity at the ORG level.

Answer (score 0):

A user with the **orgpolicy.policyAdmin** role can define an organization-level policy constraint (constraints/**compute.restrictXpnProjectLienRemoval**) that limits the removal of liens to just the following roles:

- Users with roles/owner or roles/resourcemanager.lienModifier at the
  organization level
- User with custom roles that include the resourcemanager.projects.get
  and resourcemanager.projects.updateLiens permissions at the
  organization level.

Follow the steps mentioned below:

1. Authenticate to gcloud as an Organization Admin or IAM member with the **orgpolicy.policyAdmin** role. Replace ORG_ADMIN with the name of an Organization Admin:

   ```
           gcloud auth login ORG_ADMIN
   ```
2. Determine your organization ID number by looking at the output of this command.

   ```
           gcloud organizations list
   ```
3. Enforce the **compute.restrictXpnProjectLienRemoval** policy for your organization by running this command. Replace ORG_ID with the number you determined from the previous step.

   ```
           gcloud beta resource-manager org-policies enable-enforce \
                      --organization ORG_ID compute.restrictXpnProjectLienRemoval
   ```

> Note: By default, a project owner can remove a lien from a project,
> including a Shared VPC host project, unless an organization-level
> policy is defined to limit lien removal.

For further information, go through the Google [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/provisioning-shared-vpc#protectsharedvpc).